# Unable to login in iTuneConnect with apple developer credential

Tags: ios, authentication, app-store-connect, itunes, apple-developer

Actually I have apple developer account and i am as Agent in it. But when i login to iTunesConnect with developer account credentials, it will not show developer dashboard in iTuneconnect. It shows page as image [image: img1]

instead of iTunesConnect dashboard like

[image: img2]

Comment: did you logged in developer portal ? can add certificates etc ?

Comment: Yes! I logged in developer portal. And I can also add certificates.

Answer (score 0):

As per image, seems like you're not having full rights of account. You're added with developer rights only. With developer rights, it will not allow you to see other details.

It would be great if you can check account rights once.

Comment: Hi iPhone developer, thanks for reply

Actually previous employee of my company was Agent of this developer account. I have transfered Agent role to me. Now I am Agent of this developer account.

Answer (score 0):

To access the itunesConnect Dashboard, You need a **paid apple developer account**.

Comment: Hi @rajmani, I have already purchased apple developer account for $99. But when i click iTunes with same developer credential, same issue occur.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the payment contracts within iTunesConnect.

Without these contracts you can not see any these in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already purchased apple developer account for $99. Where can i setup the payment contracts within iTunesConnect ? Please specify.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There must be privileges issue, Ask him to give you access in iTunessConnect too. Because adding agent in developer portal isn't enough to to acces iTunessConnect.

Check following link for clearance and steps to add admin/User in iTunnesConnect.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html

Check following link for steps to add user in apple developer account

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

**NOTE : Developer account and iTunesConnect are 2 entities. One need to be added in both separately to access contents**

Comment: I am Agent in my developer account. I did same as describe in link(you gave). But still it shows simple itune dashboard instead of developer dashboard.

Comment: You are agent in developer account not in iTunesConnect . These two are different things, ask him to add a new user in iTunesConnect with admin privileges.

Comment: Yes! I had submitted my query to apple developer support. i also provide them screenshots regarding my issue. Finally they resolved my problem.


Reply from them-

Thank you so much for providing the movie and screenshots. I was able to figure out the issue. I did a push of your program license agreement. For some reason, the agreement was never activated correctly back in March.